# How to apply gravity on specific body

Tags: libgdx, box2d, game-physics

Applying gravity to the physics world is easy, you just need to create a `Vector2` and set its horizontal and vertical gravity value. What if I want to create a top-down 2D game with zero gravity, and only apply gravity to specific body like a projectile motion of an arrow. Of course it's easy to have an projectile motion if you set your world to have a gravity at first.

```
float GRAVITY_EARTH = -9.8f;
Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(0, GRAVITY_EARTH);
World world = new World(gravity, true);
```

Box2d body class has a method that cancel or reverse the gravity, but I don't want to use it every time, just like in the below code example.

```
body.setGravityScale(0); // set 0 to cancel the gravity, and set -1 to reverse the gravity
```

But I want to be versatile, I want to apply gravity to specific body only. For example I'm using the method `setLinearVelocity` to move the body to specific destination. Now if the world has the gravity y of -9.8f it will automatically have a projectile motion.

```
Vector2 initialVelocity = targetPoint.sub(originPoint).nor();
initialVelocity.scl(speed); // to apply constant speed
body.setLinearVelocity(initialVelocity);
```

I tried increment the initial velocity of y to -9.8 to apply gravity. But it didnt work, what am I missing?

```
initialVelocity.y += -9.8f;
body.setLinearVelocity(initialVelocity);

// or 

body.applyForce(initialVelocity, body.getWorldCenter(), true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravity is a force, not a velocity.
Calling something like

```
Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(0, GRAVITY_EARTH);
body.applyForceToCenter(gravity, true);
```

in the step function should do it. Please note that you need to apply the force at every frame since they are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the opposing force in every step to cancel out gravity.

See the answers of [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29558/remove-gravity-from-single-body) for other options.